# Payment Methods of Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I am looking for different methods of payment using authorize.net gateway.
I am wondering if authorize.net provide methods similar express checkout and do direct payment in paypal.
I see there is card method available but I am not sure if authorize.net provide account to account payment option or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do.

https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/paypal.html

> **PayPal Express Checkout**
>   PayPal Express Checkout for Authorize.Net enables you to offer PayPal as a payment option to your customers by incorporating it within your existing API implementation.

Answer (score 0):

They do not. They are merely a payment gateway which connects a website to a merchant account. Paypal is a payment services provider and offers payment services that traditional payment gateways do not.